# How to remove double quotes from angular expression?

Tags: html, angularjs

I need this :

```
<div><div> May I help you </div></div>
```

The inner div part should be coming from angular controller :

```
<div> May I help you </div>
```

So my html will change to this :

```
<div>{{AskHelpText}}</div>
```

AskHelpText is coming from XYZController - AngularController

Currently its rendering like this :

```
<div>"<div> May I help you </div>"</div>
```

Comment: Post your XYZController.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `ng-bind-html` directive

```
<div ng-bind-html="AskHelpText"></div>
```

[read more here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

Don't forget to use angular sanitize on your app module.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide attribute `ng-bind-html` to the outer `div` and use `$sce.trustAsHtml()` in your controller.

You can try something like this:

**HTML**

`<div ng-bind-html="someName"></div>`

**Controller**

`$scope.someName=$sce.trustAsHtml(htmlVariableName);`

Comment: $sce is undefined it says

Comment: Inject `$sce` service in your controller
`yourApp.controller('cntrlName', ['$scope', '$sce', function($scope, $sce) {`